# Java synchronization between application instances

Tags: java, file, file-io

The task is multithreaded parse of json files in specific folder and it's subfolders. One of the key points is to implement synchronisation mechanism which allows file being processed by one instance of application only. Is there any ideas guys ?

Comment: Why use one application instance (= one JVM) per file? Why not multi-thread the application properly?

Comment: @Turing85 I'm using proper multi-threading with thread that scan specific folders, put files in blocking queue and then file processor threads taking these files from queue and parsing them, but i need implement that synchronization mechanism

Comment: How to make a method synchronized across all instances of a class
<https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/206732/how-to-make-a-method-synchronized-across-all-instances-of-a-class>

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java NIO's File Locking [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html)

Comment: I need another way

Comment: Can you explain why? If you need to run multiple instance of your application in diff servers. You need something like distributed locks. Redis / Redisson for example.